# Question on the definition of Rimannian metric

Tags: definition, riemannian-geometry, tensors

So I have the following definition for a Rimannian metric:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $g$ a $(0,2)$ tensorfield on $M$, s.t. $g_p$ is a scalar product on $T_pM$ and $g_p$ is positive.
Now, a $(0,2)$ tensor field is a $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear map

$\mathcal{X}(M) \times \mathcal{X}(M) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ where $\mathcal{X}(M)$ is the space of all vector fields on $M$, functions.

Now we didn't really get an explanation what $g_p$ is supposed to be.

$g_p$ has to be a bilinear function $T_pM \times T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Where do I have to put $p$ in, s.t. a function from $\mathcal{X}(M) \times \mathcal{X}(M) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(M)$ becomes a function from $T_pM \times T_pM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I really don't get it here..

Comment: A vector field is a "smooth map $s : M \mapsto TM$ with $s(p) \in T_pM$", and a function is a "smooth map $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb R$".

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M) $ then $g(X,Y)\in C^\infty(M)$ and you can evaluate it at a point. By definition
\begin{equation}
g(X,Y)|_p=g_p\,(X_p,Y_p).
\end{equation}
It may help to recall that $\mathfrak{X}(M)=\Gamma(TM)$, the space of smooth section of the tangent bundle, and $TM=\bigcup_{p\in M}\ \ T_p M$.

Comment: So we define for $v,w \in T_pM$ $g_p(v,w) $ as $g(X,Y)|_p$ where $X,Y \in X(M)$, s.t. $X_p=v, Y_p=w$, $X,Y$ exist because $X(M)= \Gamma(TM)$, right?

Comment: Also, in all the definitions it says something like for this, $g_{ij}(p) $ needs to be symmetric and positive but there is no definition for $g_{ij}(p)$. Is it right, that $g_{ij}(p):=g_p(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}_p)$ locally? I've also seen definitions for a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by defining $g_{ij}(P):=<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}|_p> = <e_i,e_j>$ where $<.,.>$ is the standard scalar product

Comment: but I don't get how you put $ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}|_p$ in the scalar product..